# 5 users won't sync with AAD Connect

Tags: email, sync, smtp, azure

I have a problem with 5 users which won't sync with Azure AD Connect!
All the other domain users works fine!

Attributes:

```
Proxy address matches:
SMTP:firstname.surname@mydomain.se
smtp:nickname@mydomain.se
```

mail:

```
firstname.surname@mydomain.se
```

mailNickname:

```
cg
```

userPrincipalName:

```
firstname.surname@mydomain.se
```

when I do a Delta and Full sync the program sees accounts, and tells me the same information like the others. But it doesn't add them in the Office 365 portal.

Does anyone here has a tip or knows what might be wrong. 
Thanks in advance and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: I've seen this happen before where some attributes are duplicates of existing users on the O365 tenant - I assume you've verified the attributes are unique that need to be?

Comment: Go to Azure Portal>Azure Active Directory Connect Health>Azure Active Directory Connect (Sync)>Sync Error to check the error details. Also refer to this document to troubleshoot:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-troubleshoot-sync-errors